# StringEnd() raises exception when match fails - PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

The following prints 'pass':

```
pattern = Word(alphanums) + StringEnd()
str=" bar "
results = pattern.parseString(str)
if 1 == len(results) && "bar" == results[0] :
    print("pass")
else:
    print("fail")
```

but this throws and exception in `parseImpl` of `class StringEnd` (when the char following 'r' in 'bar' is not a string end):

```
pattern = Word(alphanums) + StringEnd()
str=" bar foo "
results = pattern.parseString(str)  # <-- exception raised
```

as does this:

```
pattern = Word(alphanums)
str = " bar foo"
results = pattern.parseString(str,parseAll=True)
```

I would expect the 2nd/3rd parseString calls to just return an empty array, as it would obviously not satisfy the grammer.

Can anyone help me understand why?

(should be obvious, but to run you'll need 'from pyparsing import *'; also I'm on python3.2 and pyparsing 1.5.6)

Comment: what exception is thrown exactly?

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry it throws a `ParseException`, at the char following 'r' in bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning an empty list on a failed match is ambiguous - did the grammar match and just return an empty match, or did it not match at all?

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> integer = Word(nums)
>>> expr = Suppress("data:") + ZeroOrMore(integer) + StringEnd()
```

Parse some data:

```
>>> expr.parseString("data: 1 2 3").asList()
['1', '2', '3']
```

Successful parse, there just weren't any numbers here:

```
>>> expr.parseString("data:").asList()
[]
```

Exception tells you this match failed:

```
>>> expr.parseString("data: 4 Z 6 7").asList()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.6.egg\pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 12), (line:1, col:13)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll accept this with one more bit of info -

Comment: -append to prev comment- ___     

I interpret this simply as you made the design decision to signal match failures with exceptions.    ___

- Would 'None' for failure have been sufficient?    

___ - In my project, the bit I'm trying to match can be expected to fail often; I want to know if it matches to proceed with other behavior.  (Coming from a C++ background) I would want to avoid exercising code in a way I know will raise exceptions - in other words keep exceptions out of the happy path - for performance reasons.  Is this less true in Python?

Comment: Performance of exceptions is generally not seen as a major issue in Python, and for these grammars, raising a ParseException is kind of a natural unwinding of the grammar evaluation stack. So that is the implementation pattern of each ParserElement class, to either match the defined pattern or raise a ParseException. This is also a way for parse actions to add some semantic evaluation to an otherwise correct match. For instance, you could implement a range-checking action that would take a matched integer, and then raise a ParseException if the integer did not fall within a valid range.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `parseString` on a grammar, you are telling it "parse this string using this grammar, starting at the beginning".  It has to match something, or it will raise an exception.  This is doubly true when you use `parseAll=True`.  You are saying "match this entire string against this grammar".  If it doesn't all match, it's an error.  `parseString` is not an "optional" sort of match where it will just silently fail if you try to match the wrong grammar.  If something "obviously does not match the grammar", that's.exactly when it's supposed to raise an error.

You might want to try `searchString` instead.  This will just look for all matches within the string, wherever they are:

```
>>> pattern = pyp.Word(pyp.alphanums)
>>> pattern.searchString(" bar foo ")
([([u'bar'], {}), ([u'foo'], {})], {})
```